# problem in fetching receiveddate of an email with pop3 through javamail

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, pop3

I am trying to fetch email information of yahoo.de through javamail. I could get subject,from,to etc. but I am not able to get the received date of the email. I used getReceivedDate method and it returns null. Here is my code.. can anybody please help me how do I get the received date of the email with POP3 through javamail ?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class FolderFetchPop3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Folder folder = null;
        Store store = null;

        try {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            store = session.getStore("pop3");
            store.connect("pop.mail.yahoo.com","username@yahoo.de", "password of emailid");
            folder = store.getFolder("inbox");

            if(!folder.isOpen())
            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
            System.out.println("No of Messages : " + folder.getMessageCount());
            System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());
            System.out.println(messages.length);
            for (int i=0; i &lt; messages.length;i++) {
                System.out.println("*****************************************************************************");
                System.out.println("MESSAGE " + (i + 1) + ":");
                Message msg =  messages[i];
                //System.out.println(msg.getMessageNumber());
                System.out.println("Subject: " + msg.getSubject());
                System.out.println("From: " + msg.getFrom()[0]);
                System.out.println("To: "+msg.getAllRecipients()[0]);
                System.out.println("Date: "+msg.getReceivedDate());
                System.out.println("Size: "+msg.getSize());
            }
        } finally {
            if (folder != null && folder.isOpen()) { folder.close(true); }
            if (store != null) { store.close(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Check out the [Java Mail API FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#rcvdate):

> **Q:** Why does getReceivedDate() return null when using POP3?
>   **A:** The POP3 protocol does not provide information about when a
>   message was received. It may be
>   possible to guess at the received date
>   by looking at some message headers
>   such as the Received header, but this
>   is not very reliable.

So, in order to get some information about the received date check out [`MimeMessage#getHeader(String name)`](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29) and try to fetch the `Received` headers which you can try to interpret.

Comment: Any idea why it's not reliable, and what level of reliability one would expect?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher The amount of reliability depends of the tools/applications/servers that set the `Received` header. If it's not set you can't use it obviously.

Answer (score 4):

I have prepared this **simple received date resolver** get the latest date from Received header.

```
public static final String RECEIVED_HEADER_DATE_FORMAT = "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
public static final String RECEIVED_HEADER_REGEXP = "^[^;]+;(.+)$";

public Date resolveReceivedDate(MimeMessage message) throws MessagingException {
    if (message.getReceivedDate() != null) {
        return message.getReceivedDate();
    }
    String[] receivedHeaders = message.getHeader("Received");
    if (receivedHeaders == null) {
        return (Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(RECEIVED_HEADER_DATE_FORMAT);
    Date finalDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    finalDate.setTime(0l);
    boolean found = false;
    for (String receivedHeader : receivedHeaders) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(RECEIVED_HEADER_REGEXP);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(receivedHeader);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String regexpMatch = matcher.group(1);
            if (regexpMatch != null) {
                regexpMatch = regexpMatch.trim();
                try {
                    Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(regexpMatch);
                    LogMF.debug(log, "Parsed received date {0}", parsedDate);
                    if (parsedDate.after(finalDate)) {
                        //finding the first date mentioned in received header
                        finalDate = parsedDate;
                        found = true;
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    LogMF.warn(log, "Unable to parse date string {0}", regexpMatch);
                }
            } else {
                LogMF.warn(log, "Unable to match received date in header string {0}", receivedHeader);
            }
        }
    }

    return found ? finalDate : Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
}
```

Hope this helps. If you have any improvements, let me know.

Peter